# Как получить пересечение нескольких коллекций средствами linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Я получаю несколько коллекций. Объединяю их в List():

```
List<IEnumerable<CustomTable>>? customTablesSampling = new();
```

далее необходимо найти пересечение внутренних коллекций. Иными словами, получить коллекцию IEnumerable<CustomTable>, состоящую только из общих элементов среди всех коллекций из объединяющей их.

Я использовал следующий вариант:

```
IEnumerable<CustomTable>? resultTable = customTablesSampling.First();

for (int i = 1; i < customTablesSampling.Count; i++)
{
    resultTable = resultTable.Intersect(customTablesSampling[i]);
}
```

Он работает и я получаю необходимый результат. Но передо мной была поставлена задача сделать тоже самое средствами linq одним запросом.

Я пытался сделать что-то подобное:

```
IEnumerable<CustomTable>? resultTable = customTablesSampling.SelectMany(t => t.Where(j => j.Id != null))
                                                            .GroupBy(k => k.Id)
                                                            .Select(v => v.First())
                                                            .ToList();
```

Также пробовал вместо GroupBy - DistinctBy. Оба варианта лишь дублировали выбранные варианты в результирующей таблице.

Необходимо составить корректный linq запрос.

Comment: А что мешает использовать Aggregate и Intersect? Зачем вам SelectMany и GroupBy в этой задаче?

Comment: Я крайне плохо умею использовать linq. Поэтому до иных вариантов не догадался...

Comment: С Intersect вместо SelectMany, тоже был вариант, но я не смог составить его так, чтобы он находил пересечение, при условии если коллекций больше чем 2.

Comment: @iiKuzmychov пересечение, это когда элемент есть одновременно во всех коллекциях, а не в любой их них.

Comment: @aepot ой.., ну бывает))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var source = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new List<int> { 2, 3, 4, 5 },
    new List<int> { 3, 4, 5, 6 }
};

var result = source.Aggregate((IEnumerable<int> a, IEnumerable<int> b) => a.Intersect(b));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Aggregate - это тот же цикл.